# Distribute Windows 10 Special Folder Storage Over Multiple Drives

Tags: windows-10, storage

On my home Windows 10 machine I have over a TB of storage capacity, but am having a hard time making use of it. Is it possible to distribute the storage for Windows' special folders, specifically My Programs and My Documents over multiple drives, as I would have in an Enterprise environment? I've looked briefly at Storage Spaces, but that seems to be aimed more at fail-safety than actual storage management.

Comment: All user data folders (`%UserProfile%\Documents`, `%UserProfile%\Downloads`, etc. can be moved via Folder Properties > Location tab.  Generally speaking, moving system folders such as `%ProgramFiles%` isn't recommended _(if using another partition for the aforementioned user data directories a 200 - 300GB `C:` partition would be more than sufficient for almost all users)_

Comment: You can't really 'spread' your data like you are asking but you can (in addition to @JW0914 comment) use NTFS junctions to break it down further.  You can even do %ProgramFiles% using junctions but that gets tricky because there is almost always something in that folder loaded in memory.  I believe that the only thing  you can't use a junction or hard link for is hiberfil.sys.. it has a fixed location on the disk.  Every time my disk gets too full.. I move something huge to another drive and junction the folder back.

Comment: @JW0914, sort as the comment is, it seems to be a good *Answer*, instead. Perhaps include other defined folders, such as Pictures, Videos and Music.